# Passing nano a specific filename inside a function

Tags: function, shell, zsh, nano

I'm relatively new to shell in general, only recently started learning `bash` scripting and how to use it in automation. Problem is that I use `zsh` as my daily shell and would like to get into habit of using command line text editor and specifically `nano`, at least for now.

To do so (and also to practice making scripts and tweaking configuration files) I tried to make a function within `.zshrc` which would `cd` me into a particular directory I use for my [Free Writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_writing) library, then create a file with today's date as its name and enter interactive `nano` session.

Code of said function

```
function ok_go() {
    cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Freewriting
    nano $(date %d.%m.%Y)
}
```

Problem is nano doesn't really get the name, it `cd`'s into the right directory, starts a file editor but the name is blank. But for some reason, if I use `nano $(date %d.%m.%Y)` interactively (call it myself) it works as I intended, i.e start the edit of the file with a name of something like `21.04.2021.txt`

Don't really get why it doesn't work from a function call and how can I make it behave like a want. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a `+` in the date command. If you double check, you'll probably find that you ran it with the + in the terminal and neglected it in the function. It's always a good idea to copy-paste exactly from two difference sources even if the output is identical, because it's too easy to miss really minor things like a [stray period or extra space](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) that make all the difference in debugging

Comment: Hey, thanks! After all, you are completely right! I just forgot a `+` sign in my code, but I really did use it when brainstorming how to do the function. Also changed file extension to `.md` and enabled highlighting and softwrap. Dream setup! Only thing missing now is a built-in timer! Do you think it is possible to include a timer in the function, that would automatically save and close `nano` when say 10 minutes have elapsed? Can you post your comment as an answer? I would gladly accepti it!

Comment: Since it was caused by a typo or copypaste fail between your two attempts, you can close it as "not reproducible". Autosaving after a timeout in `nano` is a separate issue that I wouldn't know how to do well (I'd be very surprised and annoyed if my editor saved and closed itself just because I switched windows to answer an email)